# TTL of a dynamic arp entry in windows

Tags: windows, arp, ttl

When I run `arp -a` on my cmd I get a list of arp entries. The dynamic entries expire when their timer expires and then they are deleted from the arp cache. How can I see how much time a certain entry has left?

**I am not talking about the "base reachable time" that is used for calculating this value, I'm talking about the actual value for each entry.**

Comment: the linked answer does not answer the question, open it again please

Comment: You decided to post the question [again](https://superuser.com/q/1722411/432690), so this one should be deleted, not reopened.